# Rails 7 delete data attribute from jsonapi-serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-serializer

In my Rails 7 API app I'm using `jsonapi-serializer` gem for response data serialization. I know it follows the [JSON API standard](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/184#issuecomment-505695115) however this can be customised. I've got `user_serializer` which produces below JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "8",
        "type": "user",
        "attributes": {
            "email": "test@test.com",
            "role": "owner",
            "created_at": "2022-10-17T23:59:49.897Z"
        },
        "links": {
            "set_password_url": "some_url"
        }
    }
}
```

`user_serializer.rb`

```
class UserSerializer
  include JSONAPI::Serializer
  attributes :email, :role, :created_at
  link :set_password_url do |_user, params|
    params[:password_url]
  end
end
```

`registrations_controller.rb`

```
def create
  user = User.new user_params

  if user.save
    render json: UserSerializer.new(user, { params: { password_url: 'some_url' } } ).serializable_hash
  else
    (...)
  end
end
```

How to make it simple with this gem to be:

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "role": "owner",
  "created_at": "2022-10-17T23:59:49.897Z"
  "set_password_url": "some_url" # this attribute is not a User model field
}
```

I found [this](https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi/issues/184#issuecomment-505695115) answer but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Why are you using a gem that serializes your data in JSON-API format when you want to use a different format? Wouldn't it be easier to use a different gem for serialization, like `ActiveModelSerializers`?

Answer (score 1):

Hi in your controller just add the method .dig(:data, :attributes),

```
    render json: UserSerializer.new(user, { params: { password_url: 'some_url' } } ).serializable_hash.dig(:data, :attributes)
```